# RestSharp - cannot connect to remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

I have a problem with RestSharp request - it is working when running in Test project but returning "Unable to connect to remote server" when running inside MVC.

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://apiurl");
        var request = new RestRequest("Authenticate", Method.POST);
        request .AddHeader("Accept", "text/json");
        request .AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
        var model = new AuthenticationRequest
        {
            Username = "username",
            Password = "passowrd"
        };
        string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        request.AddParameter("text/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Same code in test is working just fine. But inside MVC on localhost I get "Unable to connect to remote server". Anyone had similar issue?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is the URL hard-coded? If not are you setting it correctly from config or wherever in the deployment location?

Comment: Check to see if the server allows outgoing connections. Could be blocked by default for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, URL is hardocoded.

Comment: Test is not in Visual Studio? Have you tried running Visual Studio in Administrator mode?

Comment: Test project and MVC project are under same solution. Tests running in VS. I'm running VS as admin

Comment: "Test project and MVC project are under same solution" are you using IIS express, and a hostname other than localhost?

Comment: Yes IIS express and localhost. Tried also with normal IIS, same result